# data not fetched on page-load event asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm fetching some data from database and displaying them on page when a button is clicked. I want the data to load automatically without any button clicked so I moved the code to page-load event but the `executescalar` returns null.Here's the code in button click event:

```
namespace bookstore.book
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectiondb"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            string route = Convert.ToString(Page.RouteData.Values["book"]);

            SqlCommand imgcmd = new SqlCommand("select URL from books where name= N'" + route + "'", conn);
            SqlCommand head = new SqlCommand("select name from books where name=N'" + route + "'", conn);
            SqlCommand authorcmd = new SqlCommand("select author from books where name=N'" + route + "'", conn);
            SqlCommand pricecmd = new SqlCommand("select price from books where name=N'" + route + "'", conn);
            bookcover.ImageUrl = imgcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            title.InnerText = head.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            author.InnerText = "نویسنده: " + authorcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            author.InnerText = "قیمت: " + authorcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code moved upwards to the page load event:

```
namespace bookstore.book
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectiondb"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            string route = Convert.ToString(Page.RouteData.Values["book"]);

            SqlCommand imgcmd = new SqlCommand("select URL from books where name= N'" + route + "'", conn);
            SqlCommand head = new SqlCommand("select name from books where name=N'" + route + "'", conn);
            SqlCommand authorcmd = new SqlCommand("select author from books where name=N'" + route + "'", conn);
            SqlCommand pricecmd = new SqlCommand("select price from books where name=N'" + route + "'", conn);
            bookcover.ImageUrl = imgcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            title.InnerText = head.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            author.InnerText = "نویسنده: " + authorcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            author.InnerText = "قیمت: " + authorcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}`
```

the error I get when in page-load event:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'
>
> System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteScalar(...) returned null.

please give me some insight to solve this problem, thank you.

Comment: Have you checked that `route` string variable has some value because in case of empty or null route value your query will not return any value. 

Also, why you are using 4 sqlcommands to pull 4 columns from books table? You can instead use one sqlcommand `Select URL, name, author, price from books where name=@Name` with ExecuteReader method. Also, always use parameterized queries to prevent sql injection attacks. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/protect-your-data-prevent-sql-injection/

Comment: you're right. thanks for the other advice on sqlcommand.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have record in `book` table for the printed `route` variable value?

Comment: Maybe its empty, because the route value is driven from the URL of that page and is valid whenever the page load, what do you think?